# Would this large scale "bubble pump" actually work?

Tags: pumps, solar, water-pressure

I have read about bubble pumps which work by heating water causing a phase change, the water passes through a one way valve and condenses thus pumping water.

Would this work at a larger scale as in my diagram below, or would the nature of the phase change mean that the pump would cavitate rather than provide suction?

[image]

Comment: `work by heating water` ... why not blow bubbles instead?

Comment: @jsotola I have a small farm and we use solar piston pumps to great effect, this was just a thought experiment on reducing the number of moving parts

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomen_atmospheric_engine

Comment: Use the condensation to drive a piston. Then you can do what ever you want to with the mechanical energy.

Comment: Is repeatedly boiling and condensing water really energy-efficient? I'd have thought it would be much worse than a normal pump

Comment: @user253751 I don't think its efficient, but I think it might be more reliable, other than 2 one way valves it has no moving parts - also a mains powered water pump would be powered by boiling water turning a turbine so it may actually end up being just as efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Your pump idea needs to have a pulsing action.
Heat the water up, generate a steam bubble, push water through the outlet valve.
Then turn the heater off, allow the steam to cool and condense, suck water in through the inlet valve.
Repeat.

This will work at quite a large scale, and I have made a couple of these in the past.

Note:  At anything larger than a mm in size, you need to have the outlet valve BELOW the heater, otherwise the steam will go out the outlet valve, and not the water.

As for cavitation, this will depend on what temp you cool the water down to.  The cooler the water, the more vacuum it can sustain without cavitation.  Room temperature will get you to about 9.8 metres of head.

Comment: Wouldn't the pulsing happen automatically, as the steam bubble leaves through the outlet valve, cold water would enter through the inlet valve dropping the temperature? Very interesting to hear you have done this before, do you have anything more you can share on this? I am now tempted to throw a few $ at an experiment...

Comment: That's what I was saying about it depending on how large it is.  For anything more than a mm or two, it would just end up bubbling like an electric kettle, no large single bubble of steam that produces a pulsing action.    At the VERY small scale (where I've worked professionally) it's definitely done with a pulsing electric power.  Pulsing very quickly, up to many thousands of times per second.   There may be a size that works with continuous power. The advantage of the system is that experimenting like this is very easy once you've put together a basic prototype.